# New dataSource with Kendo AutoComplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I've got a problem with Kendo AutoComplete. I have a form with a few fields on which I'd like to apply the AutoComplete Widget. Some of these fields are dynamically created after the user makes some action.

Here's what I did :

```
function myAutoComplete() {

    $("input.autocomplete").each(function() {

        //...Some code...

        //Kendo AutoComplete
        $(this).kendoAutoComplete({

            //Data
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                //URL
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url : "utils/autocomplete.php",
                        data : {case: acCase, ent: $(prefixTarget + ' input[id*="entreprise_id"]').val()},
                        cache : false
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "data"
                }
            }),
            select: function(e){     
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());

                switch (acCase) {
                    case 1 :
                        $(prefixTarget + ' input[id*="'+selectorTarget+'"]').val(dataItem.CLI_NUM);
                        break; 
                    case 2 :
                        $(prefixTarget + ' input[id*="'+selectorTarget+'"]').val(dataItem.ENT_NUM);
                        break;  
                    case 3 :
                        $(prefixTarget + ' input[id*="'+selectorTarget+'"]').val(dataItem.SUC_NUM);
                        break; 
                    case 4 :
                        $(prefixTarget + ' input[id*="'+selectorTarget+'"]').val(dataItem.id);
                        break;     
                }
            },
            filter: "contains",
            highlightFirst: true,
            suggest: true,
            dataTextField: "SearchField"

        //End Kendo AutoComplete    
        });
    //End each
    });   
//End function
};
```

This function is called when the document is ready or when a new element is created. Everything works fine!

I noticed that the dataSource is only called once, when the user types something in a field for the first time. What I'd like to do is call the "dataSource" each time the user enters in a field because some of the data passed in the "transport" might have been changed. In a way, I just want to call my file named "autocomplete.php" again to make a new query with new parameters.

I searched on the Internet and in the Kendo UI's docs but didn't find how to make it.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default filtering is performed client side. You need to enable server-side filter with the [serverFiltering](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverFiltering) option set to true.

Comment: That is what I have been searching for. Many thanks! I didn't really understand this section when I read it in the Kendo UI's docs for the first time.